# Best Practice for Dual Layouts in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 application that has 2 distinct layouts. One is for the end users, and the other is an admin console for managing the application.

That is usually very easy to handle since I can define a controller to use 1 layout.  This works fine for most settings since they do not involve the end user. But some of my models will. For example an admin editing a user profile vs a user.  To make this work should I have duplicate controllers for a model? One for the admin console and one for the users? Seems like I have thrown DRY out the window.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me an admin might be doing different things with a user than an end user would be doing so different controllers may not be completely unDRY.

However, if they are completely the same and you just want to have a different layout, then you can just set your layout based on the current user. Something like this would work:

```
layout :determine_layout

def determine_layout
  return 'admin' if current_user && current_user.admin?
  'application'
end
```

Comment: I had considered that but then the admin user would only ever see the admin view. But I agree with you this is probably the best method.  They can just have a non admin account when looking at user end code

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to duplicate your code. Just add an Authorization layer to your application and you can craft these features in your existent code.
To achieve this I would recomend you the CanCan gem:

> CanCan is an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts
>   what resources a given user is allowed to access. All permissions are
>   defined in a single location (the Ability class) and not duplicated
>   across controllers, views, and database queries.

You can see more and check the examples on the [project page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and there's also an [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Comment: Upvoted but I gave the answer creds to Alex because he got there first.